Are Sanitary tees marked with a CL?
I am looking at compliancy issues. I know CUPC shield is on my sanitary tee but i don't see the CL on the tee but its on the drawing. Is it needed on the tee? I know my airgap needed the FL on the cap to be compliant

Why do you need to know?

What is your applicable plumbing code and part of the world? Plumbing code varies considerably from state to state in the USA, and far more around the planet in other countries.

NSF-dwv is the only "mark" I'm seeing on a Genova 2x4 SanTee (other than brand and model numbers and national origin. They clearly use the same mold for PVC and ABS).

Nibco went with much fancier molds and has the UPC shield as well.

I have no idea what a "CL" mark would be indicating, nor what it would look like, nor what code calls for that one, if any - and I've done a considerable amount of homeowner plumbing, in the Northeastern USA, mostly under IPC rules. Without seeing the drawing it's from, I have to wonder if it's the common abbreviation for centerline...
I did find reference to CL-0 through CL-5 markings specfic to PEX pipe, but you won't see those on a drain fitting.

thanks. I wasn't able to find any markings online for any sani tees either. We have one old one in warehouse that had the CL on it. I also thought it was maybe center line. I think i may be ok what we were supplied by a vendor to use.
